# Delete everything that is not most recent

Tags: mysql, sql

Look this and try me help,

Thanks

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id < ((SELECT count(*) FROM table) - 10);
```

Comment: What is your table layout?

Comment: What on earth are you asking?

Comment: I'm a newbie sometimes...

Comment: One can either be a newbie or not. You can't be a newbie occasionally.

Comment: So what's your problem and what is your question?

Comment: MySQL or SQL? If SQL, which version?

Answer (score 1):

To delete all but the last 10 rows from a table:

```
delete from mytable
where id < (select min(id) from (
  select id
  from mytable
  order by id desc
  limit 10) x)
```

See [<kbd>`SQLFiddle`</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4adb2/1)

Comment: MySQL does not support `ALL (SELECT ... LIMIT x)` subqueries. This looks correct (and would be if MySQL had implemented that) but it just doesn't work.

Comment: @ypercube yeah - fixed (see sqlfiddle)

Comment: I'd use a join anyway. Having the updated table referenced in subqueries in the `WHERE` clause is not efficient and more important, is not safe.

Comment: @ypercube but the inner query executes once before any rows are deleted, so it is safe (I believe)

Comment: Check my answer on a similar problem: [MySQL: Delete all but last N records](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20218/mysql-delete-all-but-last-n-records/20222#20222)

Comment: Once for every row of the `mytable`.

Comment: About safety, check this issue: [Problem with MySQL subquery](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1371/problem-with-mysql-subquery)

Comment: @ypercube I disagree - it's once. There's no co-relation to the outer query. It would work equally well (execution wise) if the inner query was on another table.

Comment: Did you check the query with the delete random? How do you explain that sometimes deletes 1 row, sometimes 2 rows and sometimes nothing?

Comment: That there is no correlation does not mean that it is implemented this way in mysql.

Comment: @ypercube hmmm I accept that what is executed may not be what is coded due to optimizer rewrites, however I believe my query to be completely deterministic. If what you are saying is true, then this query should yield variable results - I have tried and failed to do get anything but correct behaviour. (p.s. I have found `RAND()` tpo be whacky - I wish the referenced question did not include it)

Comment: Yes your query is deterministic. It may even be optimized in recent version, not sure. I only commented from a general perspective, I prefer to do this in joins, not in `WHERE` when doing UPDATE/DELETE operations.